# CSS Parser - Insert mtimes

Tags: css, command-line, parsing, filemtime

What command line tool can I use to automatically insert mtimes into urls in my css files for the purposes of breaking the cache?

```
/* before */
.example { background: url(example.jpg); }
/* after */
.example { background: url(example.jpg?1271298451); }
```

Also, I would like this tool to spit out the *latest* mtime as the css files mtime.  (If the css file is still cached then the new urls will not get to the client.)

In searching the web, I have found very few tools that can do this.  I am even considering rolling my own, but have found very little in the way of css parsers that are actively maintained.  A candidate should be:

- fast (I don't want to wait 30 seconds on deployment)
- command line accessible (something like "cat foo.css bar.css | cssmtime > out.css")

#### What I've found so Far

- **[yui compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)** - initially I thought I would extend the yui compressor to do this, but found that it is implemented as a bunch of regex's and not a parser.
- **[csstidy](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/)** - last release was in 2007 and development has been suspended, but does have an option for inserting mtimes (also written in php, something I have no experience in)
- **[cssutils](http://code.google.com/p/cssutils/source/browse/)** - python sac implementation - seems to be actively maintained, but also seems like overkill for my needs.  Also, written in python which I have experience with
- **[csspool](http://csspool.rubyforge.org/)** - ruby sac implementation - I don't know much ruby, but would like to learn
- **[other sac implementations](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/SAC/)** - There are several java implementations, and a c implementation neither of which I know much about

#### What's your experience?

Have you used any of these libraries?  Was the experience positive?  Would you recommend I go with them for my purposes?

Answer (score 1):

If rolling your own is an option, you could make it a simple find/replace, no need for complex parsing here.  For example if you specified which files need re-caching by adding the querystring yourself, you would do this:

```
.example { background: url(example.jpg?<MTIME>); }
```

Then your code just needs to find `<MTIME>` and replace.  It would be about as fast as you could get and give you control over images that need re-caching and ones that don't.

Comment: I like this approach actually.  I've been using a quick awk script to do find and replace.